# Learning how to place accent marks

Tags: pronunciación, acentuación

I have learned in my Spanish studies that there are rules that most Spanish words follow in terms of accentuation.

More specifically, words fall into the categories of agudas, graves, and esdrújulas.

However, aren't there exceptions to these rules? Additionally, how can you tell which type of word is which?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few reasons why words get accents:

1. *The word does not follow natural stress.*
   The problem you'll find with this rule is that you either need to know a word's pronunciation to know how to accent it, or how the word's written to pronounce it. It's a bit of a catch 22.  But basically, when a word has irregular stress, it's accented.  The *regular* or *natural* stress for words without written accents is the following:<sup>1</sup>

   1. Words that end in a vowel, *n*, or *s* are stressed on the next-to-the-last (penultimate) syllable and are termed *graves* or *llanas*.
   2. All others are stressed on the last (ultimate) syllable and are termed *agudas*.
      Using that knowledge, you can work backwards if you know how a word is said. If it's stressed on the next-to-thenext-to-the-last (antepenultimate) or the previous (preantepenultimate?) then it always gets an accent because natural stress is never on those.
2. *Interrogative words*
   All interrogative (question) words are accented.  This is a limited list: *cómo*, *cuál*, *cuándo*, *cuánto/a(s)*, *cúyo*, *dó*, *dónde*, *qué*, *quién*.  When used as a relative pronoun, however, these words are *not* accented: *¿**Dónde** está el perro?  El perro estará por **donde** esté su dueño*
3. *Disambiguation of words distinguished by prosodic stress*
   While you might think that *te* and *té* are pronounced identically, the truth is they aren't: *té* always receives a prosodic stress, whereas *te* will always join up with another word.  That is, whenever you say *el té*, *té* will be given its own stress within the context of your sentence.  *te* will not.  *te lo dije* might as well be written *telodije* for how it's pronounced.  These words include *se/sé*, *de/dé*, among others.
4. *Prevention of hiatus*
   The Spanish system of diphthong and hiatus is very simple.  There are two types of vowels: strong (*a*, *e*, *o*) and weak (*i*, *u*).  Whenever there are two strong vowels next to each other, each is pronounced in its own syllable (this is called hiatus).  When a strong and a weak combine, the weak vowel is instead realized as a semivocal<sup>2</sup>.  Sometimes, however, the weak vowel needs to be “upgraded” to a full vowel in its own syllable.  In this case, an accent is often needed to demonstrate its full vowel.  Hence both *secretaria* and *secretaría* are *palabras llanas*, but in one, the *ia* form a single syllable, so the penultimate is the *ta* syllable.  In the second, the *i* is separated from the *a*, and this is represented with the accent which nicely also has the stress.
   There is a slight limitation within the Spanish orthographic system in that, unless the upgraded weak vowel gets the stress, it's impossible to mark whether two vowels diphthongize or not.  Hence, even though *enviar* looks to be two syllables, the *i* is really a hidden “upgraded” vowel that exists on its own syllable.  But when you conjugate, it becomes possible to mark the hidden hiatus: *envío* because the *i* now gets the stress and can receive the written accent.  In other conjugations like *enviaba*, the first *a* gets the full stress, so you just have to know that the *i* is separate.  In poetry, you can force the two-syllable pronunciation by adding a dieresis on the weak vowel: *agüa* is *á-gu-a*, but this rare and mostly done on words that normally diphthongize.
   Thankfully, if you know a word is pronounced with, for example, an *i-a* ending, you can know the *i* takes the accent.  With verbs, that's going to require a detailed enough answer to deserve its own question.
5. *Disambiguation of demonstratives and* solo **(deprecated)**
   This rule is no longer in play after the 2010 Orthography.  But prior to that, a demonstrative noun would be distinguished from an adjective by placing a written accent on it.  Likewise, *solo*, when meaning alone, went without an accent, while *solo* meaning *solamente* was given one.
6. *Disambiguation of preterite* ir/ser **(deprecated)**
   It used to be that the preterite forms of these two were distinguished.  I can't even remeber off the top of my head which one got the accents.  Also, monosyllabic verbs forms used to get accents even though there was no difference in pronunciation.  That's thankfully stopped.
7. *Marking of the single-letter words* a, o, *and abbreviation of* allí **(deprecated)**
   In the olden days, for some crazy reason, the preposition *a* and the coordinator *o* were both written *always* with an accent.  Then *o* only got it between numbers: *100 ó 200*.  Now neither get an accent in circumstance.  Going further back, *ý* was an abbreviation for *allí*, but now after years of disuse, *ý* is seen again in a handful of names like Comýn, Ýñigo, or Monteserýn.

---

<sup>1. Knowing this you can work backwards.  If a word is said with the stress on the next-to-the-next-to-the-last (antepenultimate) syllable, that is, *esdrújula*, or the next-to-the-next-to-the-next-to-the-last (preantepenultimate) syllable, that is, *sobresdrújula*, it necessarily must carry an accent, as natural stress never lands on the (pre)antepenultimate syllables.  If a word is *grave/llana* (next-to-the-last or pentultimate syllable stressed), it will need an accent if it ends in anything other than a vowel, *n*, or *s*.  If a word is *aguda* (last or ultimate syllable stressed), then it will need an accent if it ends in a vowel, *n*, or *s*.</sup>

<sup>2.  Some might prefer semiconsonant, depending on whether the weak vowel comes before or after.  It's mainly convention as the difference between the two is basically none.</sup>

Comment: Based on these rules, what causes a word like "caído" to have an accent? It ends with a vowel and is a grave so it should be fine.

Comment: That is a [Hiato](http://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiato)

Comment: @guifa muy buna tu respuesta, pero sería aun mejor que agregaras el caso de los hiatos

Comment: @emiliogort Es cierto. En cuanto vuelva a mi ordenador lo modifico, también me do cuenta de que tampoco mencioné las aes y oes con tilde.

Comment: I am still a bit confused about when a weak vowel and strong vowel combination would be treated as one syllable vs. two. For example, why wouldn't the words "militancia" and "vicio" have an accent since if the weak vowel and strong vowel form two syllables, these words should be esdrújulas. Is the general idea that two syllables are only formed by a weak and strong vowel when the weak vowel is being stressed? @guifa